# How Do I Bind to Key in Dictionary only if it exists

Tags: wpf, dictionary, mvvm, binding

I have a case where I dont know if a key exists in a dictionary, but if it does. I want to bind to it.

In this case, its a colour, so I use a converter to convert the colour and bind. This works great but only if the key exists!

I cant think of a way to setup a trigger, which checks if the key exists before I execute the binding?

Note in the code below, fieldColour may or may not exist. I would like to setup a data trigger which I can do, but I dont know how this is going to be possible.

```
<ToggleButton.Style>
  <Style>
    <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Schema.KeyValues[fieldColour], Converter={converters:Converter_StringToColour}}" />
  </Style>
</ToggleButton.Style>
```

Comment: what is your default color when you cant find key ?

Comment: add some more code to make us understand your need

Comment: I have no way to default since I am binding directly to the key

Comment: when you have an unknown key, what is the value that you receive in converter ? or convert doesn't gets called at all ?

Comment: This question has given me an idea! Thanks

Comment: hahahaha :) handle it in converter :)

Comment: I think so ill post my solution as an answer :)

Comment: Binding to dictionaries is a bad thing and will make you feel bad.  Don't do it.  There is probably an easier way to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually worked out the best way. You can pass it to a converter and let that decide if the parameter is null:

C#

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (parameter == null) return null;
    if (value == null) return null;

    string key = (parameter as string).ToLower();
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = value as Dictionary<string, string>;
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) return null;
    string colour = dict[key];

    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color));
    if (converter.IsValid(colour))
    {
        //Easter Egg.
        if (colour == "Magenta")
        {
            ErrorConsoleViewModel.Instance.LogWarning("Magenta? Really? Are you trying to blind me!");
        }

        Color newCol = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString(colour);
        return new SolidColorBrush(newCol);
    }
    ErrorConsoleViewModel.Instance.LogWarning("Colour " + colour + " not found. See C# Colour Table: http://www.dotnetperls.com/color-table");

    return null;
}
```

XAML

```
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Schema.KeyValues, Converter={converters:Converter_DictionaryStringToColour}, ConverterParameter='fieldColour'}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Schema.KeyValues, Converter={converters:Converter_DictionaryStringToColour}, ConverterParameter='fieldColour'}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="ToggleButton.Background" Value="#A9C7F0" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
```